# Strange error with a JHipster app in a microservices architecture and Docker up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, jhipster

I have generated an app with JHipster 5.0.1 version. The app has 4 components:

- UAA app for user accounting and authorizing
- JHipster Registry app
- A gateway app
- A simple microservice

I have followed all the steps in the documentation, including the steps to create docker compose file. But, then when I want to run docker-compose up I get some errors with pull permisions with my custom components.

Here are the logs

> compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('chipagames')
>   urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/images/chipagames/json HTTP/1.1" 404 60
>   compose.service.pull: Pulling chipagames-app (chipagames:)...
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker pull <- ('chipagames', tag='latest', stream=True, platform=None)
>   docker.auth.get_config_header: Looking for auth config
>   docker.auth.resolve_authconfig: Using credentials store "osxkeychain"
>   docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
>   docker.auth.get_config_header: Found auth config
>   urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.22/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=chipagames HTTP/1.1" 404 91

I have docker service running, I have created a repository in docker hub too, but I don't understand the error.

EDIT:

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    appuaa-app:
        image: appuaa
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://appuaa-mongodb:27017
            - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=appuaa
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
            - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=appuaa-elasticsearch:9300
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=;nddeanb
    appuaa-mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.6.3
    appuaa-elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:5.6.5
        command: -Enetwork.host=0.0.0.0 -Ediscovery.type=single-node

    chipagames-app:
        image: chipagames
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://chipagames-postgresql:5432/chipagames
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=;nddeanb
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    chipagames-postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.6.5
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=chipagames
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=

    users-app:
        image: users
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://users-postgresql:5432/users
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
            - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=users-elasticsearch:9300
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=;nddeanb
    users-postgresql:
        image: postgres:10.4
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=users
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
    users-elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:5.6.5
        command: -Enetwork.host=0.0.0.0 -Ediscovery.type=single-node

    jhipster-registry:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-registry.yml
            service: jhipster-registry

    jhipster-elasticsearch:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-console.yml
            service: jhipster-elasticsearch
    jhipster-logstash:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-console.yml
            service: jhipster-logstash
        depends_on:
            - jhipster-elasticsearch
    jhipster-console:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-console.yml
            service: jhipster-console
        depends_on:
            - jhipster-elasticsearch
    jhipster-import-dashboards:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-console.yml
            service: jhipster-import-dashboards
        depends_on:
            - jhipster-elasticsearch
    jhipster-zipkin:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-console.yml
            service: jhipster-zipkin
        depends_on:
            - jhipster-elasticsearch
```

Comment: You should post your docker-compose or some additional information such as entrypoint command, some configuration, env, dockerfiles...

Comment: I have added my docker-componse.yml file

Comment: It looks like `command:` in several services have only parameters but not binary.

Comment: But the error says `ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: pull access denied for appuaa, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

Answer (score 1):

You have the private repository I guess.
If it is Private repository then pull requires the docker login credentials.
Follow this link: https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/04-Dockerhub.html

With this you are able to pull the Docker Image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that docker is looking for your images appuaa, chipagames. That comes because of you haven't build them locally and docker is looking at the known repositories like hub.docker for it, without success.

You should build your applications either with

```
./mvnw -Pprod package dockerfile:build
```

or

```
./gradlew -Pprod build buildDocker
```

and then try to `docker-compose up` again

Comment: I had run `./gradlew -Pprod build buildDocker` before running docker-compose

Comment: do you see "appuaa" and "chipagames" when doing `docker images`?

Comment: No, I can't see them. In fact, if a try to run docker-compose with and single component (users) I have the same error

Comment: that means that `./gradlew -Pprod build buildDocker` it builds a different image than noted down in your compose file. Pr the build process went wrong. Check the name of the generated docker image by inspection /gradle/docker.gradle in the projects root